# jQuery hide image, change contents, show image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am looking for the CORRECT way to do the following:

```
$("#some-image").fadeOut();
$("#some-image").attr("src", "new-src.png");
$("#some-image").fadeIn();
```

For timing purposes, the following sets it up closer, but I know this is still incorrect:

```
$("#some-image").fadeOut(function(){
  $(this).attr("src", "new-src.png").fadeIn();
});
```

What is the correct way to do the following, in order:

1. Fade Image Out
2. After Image has faded, load a new src
3. After new image has completely loaded, fade image back in

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be that the new image doesn't load until after the DOM element containing it has already faded in. Ensure the image has fully loaded before calling fadeIn():

```
$("#some-image").fadeOut(function(){
    var tgt = $(this),
        img = new Image,
        src = "new-src.png";
    img.onload = function() {
        tgt.attr('src', src).fadeIn();
    };
    img.src = src;
});
```

Even better, load the image ahead of time:

```
<script>
    // Outside of $(function() {})
    function preload_img(src) {
        var img = new Image;
        img.src = src; // loads immediately, maybe even before DOMReady
    }
</script>
```

Then you won't have to worry about whether or not the image has been loaded when the user triggers your fadeIn/Out.

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback function. Once the fadeOut completes, we change the src and fade the imagein after the src has been changed.

```
$("#some-image").fadeOut(function(){
  //after the fadeout completes, change the src of the image.
  $(this).attr("src", "new-src.png").fadeIn();      
});
```